# how start range of a chunk is defined

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have created a table with the time value defined as integer (unix epoch time).  I set `chunk_time_interval` to 604800 so chunk is created weekly. I want the second chunk to be created after a week from the first entry is inserted. In my case the second chunk was getting created after 2 days only. How is the start range of the first chuck decided. In my case if I give weekly duration it will be different and if I give 10 days duration it will be different though the first entry time is the same in both cases. I am using Postgres version 11.6 for testing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately I'm not quite clear on what you are asking, could you please modify the question to be more clearer?

Comment: @Mayank Kandari Can you report when the third chunk is created? Is it after 9 days?

Comment: I created a table "timeseries" with fields key(integer), time(integer) and value (integer).  set chunk_time_interval to 604800 and  inserted first  row (1, x and 100). Expected  behaviour is first chunk should  hold values in range [x and x+604800) but when I query SELECT chunk_table,ranges FROM chunk_relation_size_pretty it show beginning range much less than x. After first chunk is created,  for second chunk onwards range values are deterministic. My question is how start range is defined for first chunk?

Answer (score 0):

> How is the start range of the first chuck decided?

The chunk ranges on the time column are calculated from the chunk time interval, so the range start is aligned with absolute zero. So the starting time of a chunk is the closest time, which is below the inserted value, and is dividable by the chunk interval. Here how it is calculated:

```c
range_start = (value / dim->fd.interval_length) * dim->fd.interval_length;
```

Thus the start of a chunk with the same data, but different time intervals, e.g., 7 days or 10 days, is different.

This also means that the first chunk is likely to be smaller than other chunks.

Note that the order of inserted data is often not strictly guaranteed. Thus second insert might have time slightly before the first insert (think about network latency to different sensors) if the application doesn't have a layer between data source and the database, which makes sure to write data in order.

> I want second chunk to be created after a week from first entry is inserted.

TimescaleDB doesn't provide ability to specify the chunk start time, since it calculates it. Your request is your application specific, which you can achieve it by applying time offset on each row when insert and then back when you read, but it might not worth the complexity. Can you update your original issue and explain why it is important? It is also possible to propose new functionality to TimescaleDB on [its issue tracker](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues).